# adding second param to action in controller in laravel 5 not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have this route:

```
Route::get('customer/{id}/invoice/{items}', 'CustomersController@invoice');
```

and this action in controller:

```
 public function invoice($id, $items){
    $items_arr = explode("," $items);
 }
```

when run the page: http://localhost:8080/pal/public/customer/1/invoice/1,2

I got this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$items' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the comma `,`

```
$items_arr = explode(",", $items);
//                      ^
```

;)